# How get user id in flutter firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new in flutter and I don't know how to write in a particular document(userId) in firestore.

I want my database is like:
users(collection)
  |-> userId
         |->name : Richie

Here is my attempt:

```
Future<FirebaseUser> user =FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
DocumentReference ref =Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid);
```

Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to await to get the `FirebaseUser` before you can access the `id`. 
I created a simple function below demonstrating this for you.

```
Future<DocumentReference> getUserDoc() async {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;

  FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
  DocumentReference ref = _firestore.collection('users').document(user.uid);
  return ref;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's work. But still i'm unable to add data in document. Here is my code:             return ref.setData(data);   Error is -> The return type 'Future<void>' isn't a 'Future<DocumentReference>', as defined by the method 'getUserDoc'.dart(return_of_invalid_type).

Comment: that another question sure

Comment: Yeah then try to post it as a new question and we will try to help

Comment: What if I want to add document to user with a specific id? I tried doing `db.collection('users').document(uid).setData(dataToBeSet)` but it doesnt work, throws a run time exception.