# Getting List of Documents from Logged in User Flutter/Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am a bit new to flutter/Firebase and I am trying to get a list of documents from within a sub collection of the logged in users collection.  Currently with the code I have it returns null for the logged in user print statement within the stream, however if I pass in the userid manually (instead of passing `uid`) it works.

### database.dart

```dart
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});


  // list from snapshot
  List<Item> _ListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    print(snapshot.documents);
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return Item(
        name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  Stream<List<Item>> get items {
    print('current logged in user $uid');
    return Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document(uid)
        .collection('items')
        .snapshots()
        .map(_ListFromSnapshot);
  }

}
```

### home.dart

```dart
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<List<Item>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService().items,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[50],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('MyApp'),
        ),
        // just a widget that uses a listview builder to make a card for each item.
        body: ItemList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### auth.dart

```dart
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // create user obj based on FirebaseUser
  User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // auth change user stream
  Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged
        .map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }
}
```

I have a feeling it's something to do with the value of uid not be available by the time the app calls it (something future or await/async related).  If I figure it out I'll be sure to post back here.  Thanks again for taking the time to look.

Comment: Hi @Rockingoutt93 yes, you are correct, it's related to the `Future` and `async` parts of the call. In your function to retrieve the users, you need to use them as the `Future` type with `async` set in the declaration. Could you please take a look at these posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54736761/how-get-user-id-in-flutter-firestore) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000825/how-to-get-the-current-user-id-from-firebase-in-flutter) to confirm if this helps you?

Comment: Please, let me know how it went @Rockingoutt93

Comment: Thanks I ended up going with a much different approach by using a FutureBuilder instead.  And specifying the following in my Future function so that I can include the user id inside of the path:
`FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with a FutureBuilder instead and was able to create a function like the following:

```
Future<List<T>> getDocs() async {
    final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;
    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();

    if (user != null) {
      ref = _db.collection('users/${user.uid}/items');
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you add your code, still stuck with similar problem

Comment: The code block above was the code I had working (it was a while back, can't remember if it was pseudo code or not).  If you post a link to a new issue I can take a look.